# Stop Stable baselines learn method when execution is terminated

Tags: python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I am using the satble-baselines3's "learn" method to train a model. The thing is that the rewards in my agent are negative and I want the agent to have the urge of stoping as soon as possible. I mean, my idea is to find a certain thing with my agent. On each step, the agent gets a negative reward for doing one more iteration, and this continues until it founds the successful state (so the more iterations the higher the reward is). My problem is that, even if my _is_done() method does return True in that case (triggering a reset from the agent), the model does not stop training. Therefore, I am concerned that the agent, instead of trying to find the successful state as soon as possible, it will do exactly the opposite, by trying to get that reset as near from the last training step as possible, which is why I want to break the learning loop when the successful state is found, so that the negative cumulative reward will be higher (lower in absolute terms) the sooner the state is found.

How can I make the learning stop in this case?

My implementation is something like this:

**Environment:**

```
def step(self, action, episode = -1, step = -1, reward_file_path = None, verbose = False):
        """"
        Equivalent to Iteration step. Method used to perform one iteration step by taking the action, observing the resulting state and computing the reward
        """
        print(f"\n\t\t************************ Current step #{self.current_step} ***************************************************")
        if episode != self.current_episode and episode != -1:
            self.current_episode = episode
        if step != self.current_step and step != -1:
            self.current_step = step
        truncated = False
        try:
             ... 

            # Calculate reward and done flag based on current state
            self._calculate_reward()

            # Store the reward
            self.store_reward(reward_file_path)
            # Returns true if the succesful state is found
            self.terminated = self._is_done()

            self.obs_end = self._get_observation()

            self.current_step += 1
        return self._get_observation(), self.reward, self.terminated, truncated, {}
```

**In my agent class:**

```
self.model.learn(total_timesteps=steps_to_train, callback=None, log_interval=1, tb_log_name=tb_log_name, reset_num_timesteps=reset_num_timesteps, progress_bar=progress_bar) # I've tried with both reset_num_timesteps True and False
```

I have also tried using a callback, but even if it returns False, the training does not stop:

```
class StopOnSuccessCallback(BaseCallback):
    def __init__(self, verbose=0):
        super(StopOnSuccessCallback, self).__init__(verbose)

    def _on_step(self):
        print("ON STEP")
        # Access the environment from the model
        terminated = self.model.env.envs[0].terminated  # Assumes that the first environment has the termination attribute
        if np.any(terminated):
            self.model.logger.info("Termination signal received. Stopping training.")
            print("Termination signal received. Stopping training.")
            return  False  # Stop training
        return True # Return whether the trainig stops or not
```

More code...

```
  callback = StopOnSuccessCallback()  
  self.model.learn(total_timesteps=steps_to_train, callback=callback, log_interval=log_interval,
                                tb_log_name=tb_log_name, reset_num_timesteps=reset_num_timesteps, progress_bar=progress_bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I finally modified my callback to, instead of getting the terminated attribute, call a public function that internatlly calls `_is_done()`:

```
class StopOnSuccessCallback(BaseCallback):
    def __init__(self, verbose=0):
        super(StopOnSuccessCallback, self).__init__(verbose)

    def _on_step(self):
        env =  self.model.env.envs[0]
        # Access the environment from the model and check the "terminated" attribute
        terminated = env.is_done()
        if terminated:
            self.model.logger.info("Termination signal received. Stopping training.")
        return not terminated # Return whether the training stops or not
```